# How the bulk modulus and Lamé coeffiencts are connected in the book of Theory of Elasticity by Landau?

Tags: tensor-calculus, elasticity, stress-strain

In the book of Theory of Elasticity written by Landau and Lifshitz (published in 1970), they make a connection of bulk modulus $K$ and Lamé coeffiencts, which are $\lambda$ and $\mu$, at the section 1.4 as follows:

$K = \lambda + \frac{2}{3} \mu$

This is achieved by considering two equivalent methods for expressing the free energy, $F$. The first one is:

$F = F_0 + \frac{1}{2} \lambda u_{ii}^2 + \mu u_{ik}^2$

where $u_{ik}$ represents a strain tensor and $F_0$ can actually be neglected; and the second one is:

$F = \mu (u_{ik} - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ik} u_{ll})^2 + \frac{1}{2} K u_{ll}^2$

where $\delta_{ii}=3$.

I tried to compare these two expressions of $F$ by using the fact that $u_{ik} = (u_{ik} - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ik} u_{ll}) + \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ik} u_{ll}$. At the end, I am stuck at this step:

$\frac{2}{3} u_{ii} u_{ll} - \frac{1}{9} \delta_{ik}^2 u_{ll}^2 = \frac{1}{3} u_{ll}^2$

In order to know if this equation is valid, I would like to ask:

i) Is $u_{ll}^2 = u_{11}^2 + u_{22}^2 + u_{33}^2$ or $(u_{11} + u_{22} + u_{33}) (u_{11} + u_{22} + u_{33})$?

ii) Is $u_{ii}u_{ll} = u_{11}^2 + u_{22}^2 + u_{33}^2$ or $(u_{11} + u_{22} + u_{33}) (u_{11} + u_{22} + u_{33})$?

iii) Is $\delta_{ik}^2 = 3$?

Comment: @bolbteppa what's the result of $u_{ii} u_{ll}$? Is it the same with $u_{ll}^2$?

Comment: @bolbteppa Following your suggestion of $u_{ll}^2 = \delta_{kk^{\prime}} \delta_{ll^{\prime}} u_{kl} u_{k^{\prime}l^{\prime}}$, if I set $k = k^{\prime} = 1$ and $l = l^{\prime} = 2$, I would have a term of $u_{12}^2$ in the result of $u_{ll}^2$. I think this may be not very good.

Comment: Sorry typed that wrong, you can write $F$ as $F = \mu \sum_{k,l=1}^3 u_{kl} u_{kl}  + \frac{1}{2}\lambda [\sum_{j=1}^3u_{jj}]^2 = \mu (u_{kl})^2 + \frac{1}{2}\lambda (u_{jj})^2$ - if you look at the index structure in the second equality one can only consistently interpret it as in the first equality. Thus working out $u_{kl}^2 = u_{kl} u_{kl} = \delta_{kk'} \delta_{ll'} u_{kl} u_{k'l'}$ just might make it clearer, but even $u_{kl}^2 = u_{kl} u_{kl}$ should be fine, using $u_{ii} u_{ll} = (\sum_{i=1}^3 u_{ii})^2$ and $\delta_{ik}^2 = \delta_{ik} \delta_{ik} = \delta_{ii} = 3$.

Comment: @bolbteppa Thank you. Just to confirm, so $u_{ll}^2 = u_{ii} u_{ll} = (u_{11} + u_{22} + u_{33}) (u_{11} + u_{22} + u_{33})$.

Comment: Yes, as a check - the derivation will not work unless you use that, go through it and compare..